# Has the Yalkut Yosef been translated into English in its entirety?

Tags: halacha, translation, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, english

I know work on the Yalkut Yosef (English) Saka Edition has been ongoing, but I was wondering if all volumes have now been released or if there’s an estimated release date for when all the books will be complete?

Comment: Asking the publisher is probably a more effective strategy than asking here

Comment: Publisher is “HaKeter Institute”, but I can’t seem to find contact information for them anywhere!

Comment: Yes,complete ...https://www.eichlers.com/yalkut-yosef-hebrew-english-complete-17-volume-set-bke-yys17.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAgaGgBhC8ARIsAAAyLfEth0oPyzgfSdz6bI4KC2GIMq4Jt61v0hzx-vcXTQqPoqYuMy-PWl8aAtDkEALw_wcB

Comment: Several places mention there will be a total of 33 volumes in the set - but I did see the Eichler’s (and others) “Complete” tag. I took it to mean as “Complete this published.”

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Elliot and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!